# everything is working fine getting id in url but not showing data against id using resource controller

Tags: laravel, controller

i m try to show data of specific user using show method(resource controller)
but getting 404 error.index,create and store functions are working fine.also
getting id in URL but its showing 404 error while calling show function
same error with edit,update and destroy.I  try without resource controller and its was working perfectly.

here is my code,

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-inverse table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           @foreach ($data as $item)
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">
                   {{$item->id}}</td>
                <td>
                   {{$item->name}}</td>
                <td>
                   {{$item->email}}</td>

                <td><a href="{{ route('show',$item->id) }}">edit</a></td>

            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
</table>
```

code of resource  controller,there is no issue with index,create and store function
only getting 404 error when i pass id as a parameter

```
  <?php
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\crud;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CrudController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data=crud::all();
        return view("index",compact("data"));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\crud  $crud
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(crud $crud)
    {
        //
        return "show";
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\crud  $crud
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(crud $crud)
    {
        //
        return "edit";
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\crud  $crud
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, crud $crud)
    {
        //
        return "update";
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\crud  $crud
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(crud $crud)
    {
        //
       return "destroy function is working";

    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::resource('user/', 'CrudController');
```

Comment: can you show how you defined this route for `show`

Comment: <td><a href="{{ route('show',$item->id) }}">edit</a></td>

Comment: @NomanAli Please always offer question details by [edit]ing your question (not by commenting under your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route definition is malformed. What you are passing into the first argument is a resource name, which can be a URI, but the last part of it is the resource name.

```
Route::resource('user/', ...);
```

This is going to interpret after the `/` as the resource name which would create a route parameter named `{}`, blank. Though this would create a route with the name `show` since there is no resource name to prepend to it.

The correct definition would be:

```
Route::resource('user', 'CrudController');
```

This does not create a route named `show`. It would be `user.show`. As `user` is the resource name.

In the Controller the parameter would be `user` not `crud`:

```
public function show(crud $user)
```

You can override the conventions used if you really want to, but I would suggest sticking within them. I can go into overriding these things if needed. [route names, route parameter name, ...]